# Is there a database of sample Apex Triggers?

Tags: apex, web

Does anyone know of a website that has sample apex triggers for common salesforce needs that could be used? With many people having similar issues it would be nice if usable apex triggers for any organization were visible for use and reference.

Comment: I'm working on an open-source project that I'll be announcing on Twitter when it's available @brianmfear, probably in the next 2-4 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

The "Apex Triggers" section of the "Intro to Programmatic App Development" course in Salesforce's Trailhead series has several trigger examples in it. See: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/trail/force_com_programmatic_beginner.

Here's one of the triggers provided in that course:

[image: trigger code]

As far as I know, there is no other website that gives as many examples of Apex triggers (yet).

[edit]
As noted in the comments below, the screenshot I provided was from earlier in the course where they are just starting to teach about triggers and what they can do. This screenshot is from much later:
[image: bulk trigger]

Comment: Including a screenshot of a trigger that has all the code in the body! I am horrified! Where is the handler? At least a services class would be an improvement. Bummer that their code is not of better quality.

Comment: Consider that the goal of such samples is to explain and teach the basics. Introducing architecture concepts at the same time may bring too much complexity to novice developers and not illustrate the essentials of such a sample.

Comment: Yes, a lot of their sample triggers are not what you'd call polished. They do a great job of walking through the steps from the very basics of what a trigger is and the various pieces of code that make it up and then further along how to "bulkify" it. This is why some of the triggers aren't something you'd write for a production org. They do teach about "bulkifying" and testing though just not in the particular screenshot I took.